# How do I find this div ? (PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser)

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

This is my code:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $title=$html->find('div#ires', 0)->innertext;
    echo $title;
?>
```

It outputs all result of the Google Search Page under the Search "BA236".

The problem is I dont need all of them and the Information I need is inside a div that has no id or class or anything else.

The div I need is inside the first

```
<div class="g">
```

on the Page, so maybe I should try something like this:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $title=$html->find('div[class=g], 0')->innertext;
    echo $title;
?>
```

But the Problem of that is, if I load the page it shows me nothing except this:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs...\simpletest2.php on line 4

So how can i get the div i´m searching for and what am I doing wrong ?

**Edit:**

> Solution:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $e = $html->find("div[class=g]");
    echo $e[0]->innertext;
?>
```

> Or:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $title=$html->find('div[class=g]')[0]->innertext;
    echo $title;
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a change to your code where I am searching for the class:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $e = $html->find("div[class=g]");
echo $e[0]->innertext;
?>
```

result:

```
British Airways Flight 236

Scheduled   departs in 13 hours 13 mins

Departure   DME 5:40 AM     —

Moscow  Dec 15      

Arrival LHR 6:55 AM     Terminal 5

London  Dec 15      

Scheduled   departs in 1 day 13 hours

Departure   DME 5:40 AM     —

Moscow  Dec 16      

Arrival LHR 6:55 AM     Terminal 5

London  Dec 16
```

I looked for the div elements with class g then I printed the count of the first element '0'

```
$e = $html-> find ("div [class = g]");
echo $e [0]->innertext;
```

Your code:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236',false);
    $title=$html->find('div[class=g]')[0]->innertext;
    echo $title;
?>
```

not `('div[class=g], 0')`

but `('div[class=g]')[0]`

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you added some explanation of what you've done to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !

Comment: @Kroe I'm sorry if I can not give you more details ^^.

Comment: Question closed

Answer (score 0):

there is no need for simple_html_dom here, it's easy to do with the builtins DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/search?q=BA236');
echo (new DOMXPath ( (@DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html )) ))->query ( '//div[@class="g"]' )->item ( 0 )->textContent;
```

in my opinion, DOMDocument + DOMXPath makes simple_html_dom.php rather pointless. the former 2 can do pretty much everything simple_html_dom can do, and are built-in native php functions, which is likely to be maintained as long as PHP itself is maintained, and the latter is a 3rd party project which seems nearly dead by the looks of it (last commit was in 2014, there was only 1 commit in all of 2014, and 2 commits in all of 2013 )

Comment: may be true but that's absolutely not the answer to my question