# How do I find this "td" with php find function?

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping

this is my code:

```
    $post = [
        'iatacode' => 'DME',
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/aptcoderes.asp');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    var_export($response);
    $html5 = str_get_html($response);
    $elem = $html5->find('td', 5);
    echo $elem;
```

> Changing my Question, as it´s half answered:
>   How do I get only the 5th "td" and not display the whole curled page ?

How do I get and display only the 6th "td" on the page i´m "curling" ?
I don´t want the rest to display ...

Comment: Alright... Show me the full code?

Comment: just corrected it

Comment: that´s all of the code

Comment: Looks fine to me... No idea why it doesn't work. Coz it works for me...

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump( $html5);` ? add it after `$html5 = str_get_html($response);` and show us the response. (Please add response in your question not in comment)

Comment: wait, just noticed the find function work, but theres still one problem then, how do I remove everything else from the page, I dont want the html to display I only want to get the html of the 6 th td ?

Comment: try this  $elem = $html5->find('td')[5]

Comment: as just wrote, no problem with php find function

Comment: it's similar to your old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814264/how-do-i-find-this-div-php-simple-html-dom-parser/47814488#47814488 remove the class

Comment: can´t you read ?

Comment: Excuse me, do you want to display only 'Boeing Codes' without seeing the whole page?

Comment: if you remove 'var_export ($ response);' you will only see the 'td' that you have chosen

Comment: yes, doesn´t even matter what to see, just show me how to script that please

Comment: oh thank you, that´s it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you remove 'var_export ($ response);' you will only see the 'td' that you have chosen

```
<?php

$post = [
        'iatacode' => 'DME',
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.airlinecodes.co.uk/aptcoderes.asp');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //var_export($response);
    $html5 = str_get_html($response);
    $elem = $html5->find('td', 5);
    echo $elem;

?>
```

Comment: there is no need for simple_html_dom here, this is trivial to do with DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName , which is built-in to every php installation with the XML extension installed, which is pretty much all of them. and in my opinion, DOMDocument+DOMXpath (which are both builtin to the XML extensions) makes simple_html_dom rather pointless.

Comment: @hanshenrik yes, you're right, I've got some dirty code, from an old code I got, my fault

Answer (score 0):

to display the 6th td:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo (@DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $response ))->getElementsByTagName ( "td" )->item ( 6 - 1 )->textContent;
```

(the -1 is because it starts counting at 0, thus item #6 is actually td #7)